# How to give an Azure Devops private Windows Agent access to SupportedAPIs-x64.xml?

Tags: windows, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When I running my Azure Devops build pipeline for a UWP app locally via a private Windows Agent, it complains that it cannot access `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit\SupportedAPIs-x86.xml`

The agent service is using the default suggested user `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`.

So far I tried, without success:

1. to run the service with my (admin) credential (I'm using an hotmail account to log on my machine) but it doesn't want to (error 1355)
2. give `Everyone` `Read & Execute` rights on the folder the service is denied access to

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if you're still having this issue but this is what worked for me. Anyone else that finds this can try this out.

I would recommend trying this out as a sanity check, but my issue was permissions.

- If you run `services.msc` and find `Azure Pipelines Agent` then click
  on the service to highlight it.
- Right click, go to properties
- Navigate to the `Log On` tab at the top
- Change the username and password to a known domain admin account
- Click ok and restart the service.

Now run your pipeline again and see if it can connect and publish your files. If it does then its a user/permissions issue.